# How to clear Cordova plugins cache?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I am working on an iMac computer with Ionic Cordova projects. I cloned [a plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@selligent-marketing-cloud/selligent-cordova) on my github account into [an own repo](https://github.com/axelcostaspena/MobileSDK-Cordova) and installed the plugin into an ionic app with `ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/axelcostaspena/MobileSDK-Cordova`. Now everytime I try to install the original plugin from the original repository with `ionic cordova plugin add @selligent-marketing-cloud/selligent-cordova` it resolves the plugin id to my github repository and installs mine. See picture. How can I clear the cache that causes that resolution?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is cordova plugins are stored in npm cache of your computer So to remove that use `npm cache clean --force` Hopefully this would fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what layers Ionic adds to the mix, but for straight Cordova, you'll need to look at the `config.xml` and `package.json` files to make sure there's no old references in there. So:

- Call `cordova plugin rm <plugin-name>` to remove the plugin locally
- Clean out the references in `config.xml` and `package.json`
- Call `cordova plugin add <plugin-name>` to add the plugin from the correct location.

Comment: confirmed, no references, same scenario

Comment: OK. I haven't dealt with scoped packages before (none of my plugins need it). But it looks scoped packages also copy stuff into the `node_modules` directory, which may need to be cleaned out as well (see https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope for the details). Hope that does the trick!